# Load ML model to Orange

Tags: python, pickle, random-forest, orange

I saved a RandomForest model in Pickle as "sav" file and I want to load it to an Orange Workflow, but it turns out that "sav" files cannot be loaded to Orange.

How can I load a ML model written in python to Orange workflow?

Comment: Have you tried saving the model into another file extension ? When saving a model through pickle, the extension makes no difference. I am not familiar with Orange, but if they explicitly block `.sav` extensions, try another one.

Comment: Default extension is .pkcls. Also, make sure you load it with the Load Model widget, not with Load, which only loads data tables.